# How do I exchange data via JSONP using jQuery with Safari?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, safari, jsonp

I use jQuery to exchange data using JSONP with a python server, which works very fine, e.g. in Chrome.

But in Safari it does not work. Looking in the Safari console I get the error "[Error] Failed to load resource: Die Netzwerkverbindung wurde unterbrochen. (here, line 0)". So there seems to be a network error in Safari. Looking at the server side I can see, that the request reaches the server. There it is processed in a right way and a reply is generated. But the server's reply then can't be processed in Safari.

```
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

    $.ajax({
       url : "http://127.0.0.1:8888/url/here?callback=?",
       data: {request: "get_text", value: " "},
       dataType: 'jsonp',
       beforeSend: setHeader,
       success: function(data){
         console.log(data)
         $("#page_content").html(data.reply);
       },
         error: function (request, status, error) {
         console.log(error );
       }  
    });

    function setHeader(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
        }
```

I googled a lot and tried several implementations. I also tried to change the IP with the hostname. I also added the setHeader function, but that did not solve the problem, either.

How can I exchange data with JSONP (with jQuery or even with Java Script in general) in Safari? Does anybody know a working implementation?

Comment: What is the response if you open `http://127.0.0.1:8888/url/here?callback=boom` in new tab?

Comment: If I put your link in a new tab, I get no response in each browser, but this is like it should be. When I but this link `http://127.0.0.1:8888/url/here?callback=myFunction&request=get_text&value=+&_=1439740119053` in Chrome, I get this reply: `({"reply": "This is a test."})`.

Comment: But I get it only in Chrome. In Safari I get the same error message like before.

Comment: Response must be `myFunction({"reply": "This is a test."})`.

Comment: Thank you. I changed the server code. Now the reply is `myFunction({"reply": "This is a test."})`. In Chrome it still works. But in Safari the error still is the same.

Comment: I also checked the code with jQuery. Now there I get the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunctionjQuery110205097753282170743_1439741593196 is not defined`.

Comment: I checked the connection with the browser using telnet. I think it already is wrapped using the jQuery function: 

`telnet 127.0.0.1 8888
GET /url/here?callback=jQuery1102080470972484909_1439741576320&request=get_text&value=+&_=1439741576321

jQuery1102080470972484909_1439741576320({"reply": "This is a test."})
Connection closed by foreign host.`